# Force a plugin to use different version of jQuery

Tags: jquery, slider

Looking at the topic, please dont mark my question unproductive. I know the solution is to use jQuery.noConflict and specify a handle instead of jQuery/$. But somehow this is not working for me.

There is this code written in dark age using jQuery 1.4 with lot of live methods. I added a new module using a slider plugin (slick.js) which works on 1.6 and above. How can add jQuery 1.6+ and force only my slick plugin to use the 1.6+ version.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you mean "somehow this is not working for me"? What wasn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding the latest library on top and using jQuery noconflict. Thanks !